# Display phone number in more readable format

Tags: python, django

Please tell me how to correctly solve the following problem

There is a phone number in the database. On the site it is displayed in the same form in which it is recorded in the database

```
+1234567890
```

And I need this number to look like this, on the site page without modification in the database

```
+(123) 456-7890
```

**views.py**

```
def Data(request):
    card = Cards.objects.filter(is_published=True)
        context = {'card': card}
        return render(request, 'templates/cards.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
```

**cards.html**

```
{{ card.phone }}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Create a template tag call it `phone_number_format` that formats your code, use it like `number|phone_number_format`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django doesn't format numbers on it's own. However you can build your own function to do that. Consider using `python-phonenumbers` ([link](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers)). Create another function for this in your **models.py**:

```
import phonenumbers

class Cards:
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    .....

    def formatted_phone_number(self, country=None):
        rtval = phonenumbers.parse(self.phone, country)
        return rtval
```

And then in your `template`:

```
{{ card.formatted_phone_number }}
```

**`NOTE:`** You can't directly pass parameters from your template. So, the function has to know beforehand which country format will you be using.

Comment: Shiri, hello! I like your option, I tried to apply it, but in my place where the phone number should be, "None" comes out.

Comment: I figured it out. Need to add at the end 'return rtval'

Answer (score 0):

You could write this helper function:

```
def insert_str(string, str_to_insert, index):
    return string[:index] + str_to_insert + string[index:]
```

and then use it to insert the characters where needed. If the location of the parentheses is fixed (same for each phone number like in the example you provided) then you could simply do this:

```
phone = insert_str(phone, '(', 1)
phone = insert_str(phone, '(', 5) # there's already an extra '('
phone = insert_str(phone, ' ', 6)
phone = insert_str(phone, '-', 10)
```

Comment: Igor Perić, Hello! Thanks for the answer!